# Equivalent of CakePHP 2.x `getPath()` in Tree Behaviour for CakePHP 3.x

Tags: cakephp, tree, cakephp-3.0

In CakePHP 2.x there is a method on the [Tree Behaviour](https://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/core-libraries/behaviors/tree.html#querying-and-using-your-data) called `getPath()` which allows you to obtain the path of a given node from the top of the tree.

For example `$this->Navigation->getPath(33)` gives me an array showing how to get to node 33 of the tree, from the top.

I have some data which has been put in an application built in CakePHP 2.x however another application is built in CakePHP 3.x and needs to read in this data.

I have configured the **3.x** application as follows:

```
// src/Model/Table/NavigationsTable.php
namespace App\Model\Table;

use Cake\ORM\Table;

class NavigationsTable extends Table {

    public function initialize(array $config)
    {
        $this->addBehavior('Tree');
    }
}
```

The controller is attempting to use the `getPath()` method:

```
// in src/Controller/NavigationsController.php

$Navigations = TableRegistry::get('Navigations');
$nav_query = $Navigations->getPath(33);
debug($nav_query);
```

This gives an error message:

**Unknown method "getPath"**

I assume this is because `getPath()` isn't in CakePHP 3.x's Tree Behaviour. Is there some equivalent function that does this? I cannot see it in the docs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Path retrieval has been moved into a finder, the `path` finder:

```
$nav_query = $Navigations->find('path', ['for' => 33]);
```

See also

- **[Cookbook > 3.x Migration Guide > 3.0 Migration Guide > TreeBehavior](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/appendices/3-0-migration-guide.html#treebehavior)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Behaviors > Tree > A Quick Tour](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/behaviors/tree.html#a-quick-tour)**
- **[Cookbook > Database Access & ORM > Retrieving Data & Results Sets > Using Finders to Load Data](https://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/orm/retrieving-data-and-resultsets.html#using-finders-to-load-data)**